# Return data from restler that is in the service layer Node

Tags: node.js

I am using reslter to return data from an api.

I have no problem with it when i place the code in the controller.  How ever I want the restler code to be at the service layer not in the controller.
The service does the job but then gets stuck and never returns the data to the controller

Controller

```
exports.getProductCategories = function(req,res){

graze.getProductCategories(function(data){
    return res.send(data);
});
```

};

Service

```
exports.getProductCategories = function() {
rest.get('http://www.somesite.com/api/products/categories').on('complete', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return (data);
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed this, was missing the callback from the service layer !

```
exports.getProductCategories = function(callback) {
    rest.get('http://www.somesite.com/api/products/categories').on('complete', function(data) {
        return callback(data);
    });
});
```